# increasing sequence in a dense subset converging

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question. Assume we have D a dense subset in $\mathbb{R}$. Then why we can always find a strictly increasing sequence in D converging to any $a\in \mathbb{R}$? Since D is dense, we can always find a sequence in D converging to a, but how we know we can always find a strictly increasing one? Thanks!

Comment: In case you do not aware, the previous answer is not completely correct. Please see the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $c\in \mathbb R$, let $a_1\in D$ to be smaller than $c$. Then find $a_2\in (\max\{a_1, c-\frac{1}{2}\}, c)\cap D$, $a_3\in (\max\{a_2, c-\frac{1}{3}\}, c)\cap D$ etc. (By induction of course)

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then what you're saying here is that any sequence in $D$ $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \cdots < c$ will converge to $c$, but that is not true.

Comment: You are all correct. Let me edit the answer